# while loops in Python

Tags: python, while-loop

I want to use a while loop in this program instead of a for loop, but I don't know how and where to start? Any help would be apprecieated!

```
def password():
    guessCount = 0
    password = input("Anna please enter a password here\n:")
    guesser = input("Guesser please enter your name here\n:")
    print("Welcome",guesser,"to the Password Guessing Game.\nYou have 8 attempts to guess my password.\nGood Luck!")
    for count in range (8):
        passwordGuess = input("Guess the password\n:")
        if passwordGuess == password:
            guessCount = guessCount + 1
            print("Well Done!")
            print("It took you",guessCount,"attempt(s) to guess the password!")
            break
        else:
            guessCount = guessCount + 1
            print("Try again")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow :) What language is this? Please add a tag for that language. Also, why would you want to use a `while` loop here?

Comment: If you search for "user input while loop" you will find the general pattern for that. You might even find it in the language you're using.

Comment: I don't know why you would want to do this, but you could literally swap the word for with while and have a `count=0` before the loop and it will all work.

Comment: Remember always to search on Google before posting a question. If your question is of the variety "How do I generally use <some common feature>?", then there are probably countless explanations online.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do something similar to a for loop you could write something like this.

```
x = 0
while x in range(8): #alternately while x<8:
    ...
    x +=1
```

this will do the same thing as for x in range(8).